# Gradle can't resolve androidx.ui:ui-tooling dependency by google() repository

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I want to use the `@Preview` annotation in my brand new Jetpack Compose for Desktop project. However gradle is just not getting it done to fetch the dependecy for that.

my `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0"
    // __LATEST_COMPOSE_RELEASE_VERSION__
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version (System.getenv("COMPOSE_TEMPLATE_COMPOSE_VERSION") ?: "0.1.0-build113")
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "KotlinJvmComposeDesktopApplication"
        }
    }
}
```

It just is not being resolved

Answer (score 11):

Accordingly to the documentation, it should be working for alpha07, but for alpha08 it changed to `androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha08`, so, if you can upgrade to alpha08, you can see if it works.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/ui#declaring_dependencies